# python agnostic code calling a Windows DLL

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, dll, python-2.x

All I am trying to come up with python agnostic code for calling a Windows DLL.  By python agnostic I mean that I'd like it to work equally well in Python 2, Python 3, cygwin CPython, Windows CPython.  Ultimately I'd also like it to work in Jython and IronPython too, and MSYS2 as well.

I have read Wu Yongwei's very good article on Stdcall and DLL tools of MSVC and MinGW, and several other stackoverflow articles - it seems that my goal isn't all that common.

With trial and error I have come up with two ideas that seem to work but I am not sure if they really address the "calling convention" ABI issues covered in Wu Yongwei's article.

The first way that kind of works in Python 2 and 3 and in Cygwin CPython and Windows CPython is this:

```
import os, sys, platform, re
'''Make Wide'''
def makeWide(instring):
    outstring=''
    python_version_int = sys.version_info.major * 1000000 + sys.version_info.minor * 1000 +  sys.version_info.micro
    for idx in range(0,len(instring)):
        if python_version_int < 3000000:
            outstring=outstring+instring[idx:idx+1]+chr(0)
        else:
            outstring=outstring+instring[idx:idx+1]
    return outstring
python_platform_short=re.sub(r"_.*$","", platform.system() , 1 ).lower();
Windows_System32_User32_DLL_win = 'C:/Windows/System32/User32.dll'
Windows_System32_User32_DLL_cyg = '/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/User32.dll'
MB_ABORTRETRYIGNORE = c_long(2)
Windows_System32_User32_DLL = Windows_System32_User32_DLL_win
if python_platform_short == 'cygwin':
    Windows_System32_User32_DLL = Windows_System32_User32_DLL_cyg
if python_platform_short == 'cygwin':
    user32=cdll.LoadLibrary(Windows_System32_User32_DLL)
else:
    user32=windll.LoadLibrary(Windows_System32_User32_DLL)
user32_MessageBoxW=getattr(user32,"MessageBoxW")
message_box_window  = c_void_p(0)  # HWND
message_box_title   = c_wchar_p('Hello')
message_box_message = c_wchar_p('Hello world!!')
message_box_flags   = MB_ABORTRETRYIGNORE
user32_MessageBoxW(message_box_window, message_box_message, message_box_title, message_box_flags )
```

The makeWide function works but seems to be replaceable with the c_wchar_p function.  The makeWide function uses duck-typing/python version reflection (via sys.version_info) to address differences in the string implementation in Python 2 and 3.  This method needs to use duck-typing/os reflection (via platform.system) to work around the fact that Cygwin CPython doesn't have ctypes.windll, but Windows CPython does.  I am not really sure if Cygwin ctypes leaves the Stack in a sensible state, or if there is a way to detect or work around this.

The second way that sort of works in this:

```
from cffi import FFI
import six
class Win:
    def message_box(self, hwnd, lptext, lpcaption, utype):
        ffi = FFI()
        cdefStr="""
        int __stdcall MessageBoxW(void *    hWnd,  const char16_t *    lpText, const char16_t *    lpCaption,  unsigned int     uType);
        """
        print("DEBUG : cdefStr = " + cdefStr )
        ffi.cdef( cdefStr );
        user32 = ffi.dlopen('C:\\Windows\\System32\\user32.dll')
        if( hwnd == 0 ):
            hwnd=ffi.NULL;
        textSize=len(lpcaption)
        lpcapForCType = "const char16_t[" + str(textSize+2) + "]"
        lpcapForC = ffi.new( lpcapForCType )
        for i in range( 0 , textSize ):
            lpcapForC[i]    = six.unichr(   six.indexbytes( six.ensure_binary( lpcaption.encode("utf-16LE") ) ,(i*2)) + 256 * six.indexbytes( six.ensure_binary( lpcaption.encode("utf-16LE") ) ,(i*2)+1)    )
        lpcapForC[textSize] = six.unichr(0)
        textSize=len(lptext)
        lptextForC = ffi.new("const char16_t[" + str( textSize + 2 ) + "]" )
        for i in range(0,textSize):
            lptextForC[i]   = six.unichr(   six.indexbytes( six.ensure_binary( lptext.encode("utf-16LE")    ) ,(i*2)) + 256 * six.indexbytes( six.ensure_binary( lptext.encode("utf-16LE")    ) ,(i*2)+1)    )
        lpcapForC[textSize] = six.unichr(0)
        utype=ffi.cast("unsigned int",utype);
        user32.MessageBoxW(hwnd, lptextForC, lpcapForC, utype)
msg = six.u("Test with umlaut: ") + six.unichr(0xe4)
w = Win()
w.message_box(0, msg, msg, 0)
```

This attempts to use six and and encode("utf-16LE") to address the string differences in Python 2 and 3 and uses cffi to call the dll.  Again I am not quite clear if this addresses the stack question.

A third way which would allow me to directly address the ABI and stack questions is to drill all the way down to assembly with pycca but I haven't learned enough x86 assembly yet to try that - though I have been reading the nasm documentation on calling conventions and the related wikipedia articles.  I think that I will then be able to get Jython working using JNA, but am still learning about IronPython and relevant python packages.

Can anyone help me with the cffi, ctypes or pycca methods?  Any suggestions for IronPython or Jython?